# meaning difference: viewing rates vs. viewing ratings

Tags: phrase-meaning

Could anyone tell me about the difference between viewing rates and viewing ratings? Do they have the same meaning?

I'd appreciate your help.

Comment: When you looked up “rates” and “ratings” in the dictionary, why didn’t that help?

Comment: See Rob Lambden's reply and find out where the confusion arises.

Comment: That someone graciously attempted to answer your question doesn’t absolve you from conforming to ELL’s guidelines.

Comment: The reason why  the terms are confusing is pretty straightforward.

Comment: That also does not absolve you from following the guidelines and showing your research.

Comment: Is there any research involved in this thread: https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/220775/as-meaning-in-this-sentences ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general rates means the frequency with which something has happened, and ratings means how it is scored.

So, strictly speaking, viewing rates means how often something has been viewed, and viewing ratings means how the viewers rated (or scored) a program that they viewed.

However, you may find viewing ratings being used to indicate how different programs have been ranked according to how many people chose to watch them - so in this context it can effectively mean the same thing as viewing rates.

Viweing Ratings has been used for many years for terrestrial television (where users choose which program to watch at a particular time).  I expect that for on-demand services (where users to choose which program to watch without being limited by when it's available) viewing rates may be used more frequently.