# AS meaning in this sentences

Tags: meaning, word-usage, prepositions, word-meaning, sentence-meaning

**"As a beginner, I am happy that I learned a new thing."**

**You will recognize this as your DoReMi-s.**(https://youtu.be/n2z02J4fJwg at 4:52)

What is the meaning of the "AS" there and when do we use that? 
In depth answers would be appreciated.

Similarly:

> Do I have your word as a lawman not to shoot me down like a dog in the street?

Can you explain this sentence?

Can I understand it as a lawman wouldn't shoot down people on the street or wouldn't have his word or what?

Answer (score 6):

In this sentence, "as" is a preposition.  It means "In the role of":

It forms a prepositional phrase which describes the role of the speaker.  A person can have many roles in their life, and sometimes we want to emphasise that we are speaking with a particular expertise or perspective:

> As a parent, I am concerned about youth crime.

In this case, the beginner can't speak from a postion of expertise. The beginner can't say if the teacher is right or wrong, but the beginner can give us their opinion of how clear the teaching was, and whether they learnt anything new.

For the "lawman", a "lawman" is expected to be honest. So if I ask for your word *as a lawman*, I mean that "You have the role of a lawman, in that role you must be honest. Can you make an honest promise to me?"

Comment: Note that the speaker *could* have said something like: *As a beginner, I am happy that I learned a new thing. But **as a father with financial responsibilities**, I wish I could have been paid to attend the training course.* As you say, a person can have many roles in their life - and *sometimes* they might want to juxtapose the different reactions of multiple "aspects" of their "identity".

Comment: Can you explain "in the role of" more in-depth?

Comment: No. Can you explain what is unclear.

Comment: Do I have your word as a lawman not to shoot me down like a dog in the street? Can you explain this sentence? Can I understand it as a lawman wouldn't shoot down people on the street or what?

Comment: Also could you say the meaning of "as" in the second sentence. That would be deeply appreciated.

Comment: ... "as" is a preposition. It means "In the role of":

Comment: You will recognize this in the role of DoReMi-s. What does that supposed to mean?

Comment: I REALLY REALLY APPRECIATE YOU. But I have one last question, it is about the usage of "as" in questions. Just like "As a beginner, what should I learn first?" and "As a group unfamiliar with RPGs, how do I encourage my players to read the rulebook?"

Comment: And "Things we do as a couple".

Answer (score 0):

Mostly “As” is used when you you are comparing two different things having some common similarities.

Here are some basic uses:-

1. Adverb- used for comparisons

   Eg: Her voice is sweet as honey.

   2.Conjunction -to join 2 sentences(in the place of 'because')

   Eg: She did not go to school as she was not feeling well.

   3.Preposition

   Eg: He was selected as the captain of the football team

Here in your sentence As is preposition.

https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/441863/can-a-sentence-start-with-as-is-it-okay

https://www.quora.com/Can-you-start-a-sentence-with-as