# AS a LAWMAN preposition

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, prepositions, word-meaning, sentence-meaning

**Do I have your word as a lawman not to shoot me down like a dog in the street?**.

I don't understand the "as a lawman" part. Why did he use "as"?

This quote is from the movie Django Unchained.

https://getyarn.io/yarn-clip/5b3a8cdc-85b1-498a-addd-c95dd6c2ad79

Comment: What did you find when you looked up “lawman” in the dictionary and why didn’t that help?

Comment: Because I know what lawman is. I am just confused why he used "AS" and I mentioned it in my question. Why off-topic?

Comment: This is much the same as your [previous question](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/220775/as-meaning-in-this-sentences).

Comment: So you looked up “as” and why didn’t that help? The more people understand about what you’ve already tried to do to answer your question, the better their answers will be.